# How to get the src of the image within a dynamic DIV with $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this

I'm trying to get the src of the image, but the div is dynamic, then appears several times on the page, when I click on the DIV, he always gets the first frame and not the DIV clicked, how can I use `$(this)` correctly? Follows the code I'm using:

```
<section class="clientes" role="region">
    <a href="" title="Cliente" class="group">
        <img src="img/image01.jpg" alt="" />

        <h2>The title</h2>

        <p>content here</p>
    </a>
</section>
```

```
<script>
$("body").on("click", ".clientes", function(){
    var pega = $(".clientes .dsp-none img").attr('src');
    $(this).find("a").attr("href", pega);
})
```

Comment: I don't see any elements with class "dsp-none" in your code ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take advantage of the fact that jQuery arranges for `this` to refer to the clicked DOM element:

```
var pega = $(this).find(".dsp-none img").attr('src');
```

You may or may not want to use `.prop("src")` instead of `.attr()`.

Comment: Note that the ".dsp-none" part of that selector doesn't match up to the code you posted.